# Prove $\log(x) < n(x)^{1/n}$, for all positive integer values of $n$, and $x > 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, logarithms

Given that $$lg(u) < u$$ is always true, how do we use that to prove that $$lg(x) < n(x)^\frac 1n$$

These are the steps that I have taken so far:

$$1: lg(x) < n(x)^\frac 1n$$

$$2: \frac {lg(x)}n < x^\frac 1n$$

$$3: lg(\frac {lg(x)}n) < lg(x)^\frac 1n$$

$$4: lg(\frac {lg(x)}n) < \frac 1n lg(x)$$

$$5: \frac {lg(x)}n < x$$

$$6: lg(x) < nx$$

In which case, since $$lg(u) < u$$ is always true, it thus proves that $$lg(x) < nx$$

I know that I'm probably doing something wrong, especially moving between steps 4 and 5, because the $$\frac 1n$$ shouldn't just disappear like that, but aside from doing this I'm totally stumped.

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks, guys!

Comment: The step from $4$ to $5$ is wrong because of $exp(\frac{1}{n}lg(x))=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$, arriving at the inequality at $2$, so this approach does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 4 holds because it is $\log u < u$ with $u={\log x\over n}$, and so the proof ends there, by noticing that steps (1)-(4) are actually reversible.

Comment: (+1) Nice catch. That happens before the argument is derailed in step 5.

Comment: (+1) Ach... how'd I miss that? Oh man, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The step from $(4)$ to $(5)$ seems to be the problem. Here is a different approach.

For $u\gt0$, we are given
$$
\log(u)\lt u\tag{1}
$$
For $n\gt0$, substitute $u\mapsto u^{1/n}$ to get
$$
\frac1n\log(u)\lt u^{1/n}\tag{2}
$$
Multiply by $n$ to get
$$
\log(u)\lt nu^{1/n}\tag{3}
$$
The step from $(2)$ to $(3)$ is valid if both sides are greater than $0$. However, $(3)$ is trivially true if $\log(u)\le0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you start from:
$$ \log u < u $$
and the function $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$ is non-negative, set $u = x^{1/n}$. Then:
$$ \log  x^{1/n} <  x^{1/n} $$
and given that $\log  x^{1/n} = \frac{1}{n} \log  x$, the next step is: 
$$ \frac{1}{n} \log  x  <  x^{1/n} $$
which gives you the result,  since $n$ is positive.

Indeed, there is a tigher inequality:
$$ \log x \leq n\left( x^{1/n} -1\right) \leq x^{1/n} \log x $$
with equality attained at $x=1$, as illustrated below for $n=2$:
[image]

Comment: Since you are substituting $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$, that function does not need to be non-decreasing. To *apply* $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ to both sides  of the inequality, we would need it to be non-decreasing.

Comment: Indeed. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can prove the inequality :

$$f(x)\ :=\ lg(x)-nx^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$f '(x)=\frac{1}{x}-x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}=x^{-1}(1-x^{\frac{1}{n}})$$

The only root of $f '(x)$ is $x=1$. Because of $lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=-\infty$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=-\infty$, $-n$ is the global
maximum of $f(x)$. Hence, $f(x)<0$ for all $x>0$.